# SSL error while opening input stream

Tags: java, ssl

I guess I am trying to understand how SSL works, I have grails based application as part of application process we have to open "https" connection to a 3rd party application.
But running into following exception

```
"sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"
```

Though connection to the URL works fine but error happens when I try to open input Stream for reading data. Question is if there is certificate problem shouldn't I have problem while opening connection ?
code snippet is attached

```
try{
            URL url= new URL("https://.../..")
                def c = url.openConnection()
                println("connection successful with Merchant")
            def result = c.inputStream.text?.trim() // results in error
            println(result)
        }
        catch (Exception exp){
            println("error !!!")
                println(exp.getMessage())
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common problem for people starting out with SSL and certificate management.  I answer this question with very detailed examples and commands in an article titled, "Importing non-well known certificates" on my blog [AllInGeek.com](http://www.allingeek.com/importing-non-well-known-ca-certificates/).

Comment: While my examples are run in a Linux environment, if you are on Windows, the same command line arguments for keytool should work.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. The issue I am stuck with is I am trying to deploy an application in Amazon EC2 and currently there is no easy way to update trust store. Trying to figure out my options one strange thing I am running into is similar/same certificate by other vendor works fine while I am running into problem with the vendor only. Both those vendors are certified by verisign.if you look at certificate of these 2 it looks exactly same https://payment.atomtech.in/paynetz/epi/fts
https://www.billdesk.com/pgidsk/pgijsp/citicard/citibank_card.jsp

Answer (score 0):

This simply means that the web server or the URL you are connecting to does not have a valid certificate from an authorized CA.

You  could verify this with another ssl site 
or follow the steps here:

http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=210

to work around the issue by importing the servers certificate.